# Use memory from 2 Nodes for a Job - SLURM

Tags: cluster-computing, job-scheduling, hpc, slurm, sbatch

I have a MPI job which needs a memory greater than the maximum memory available on 1 node. I am trying to now start the job on 2 nodes, which would use the memory from 2 nodes, at least that is the idea. The script below blocks CPUS from 2 nodes, but I don't see the memory being used from 2 nodes. How do I use the memory from 2 nodes?

```
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --mem=0
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=0
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=8
mpirun -np 16 mppdyna ncpu=16 i=xxx.key
```

Comment: That script should give you access to the whole memory of two nodes. Are you sure Slurm does not give you the memory?
Oh, and --mem and --mem-per-cpu are mutually exclusive. Not sure what happens if you set both to 0, it may work in that case. But you should remove one of them.

Comment: @MarcusBoden You are right. It did indeed use the memory from 2 Nodes. I just realised that the process demanded even higher memory than the memory of 2 nodes put together. Which I did not expect initially.